# How to configure depend.el in emacs org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-depend.html

In the bottom of the webpage,"Advanced Triggerring Example"--

```lisp
{(defun mm/org-insert-trigger ()
"Automatically insert chain-find-next trigger when entry becomes NEXT"
(cond ((equal org-state "NEXT")
     (unless org-depend-doing-chain-find-next
       (org-set-property "TRIGGER" "chain-find-next(NEXT,from-current,priority-up,effort-down)")))
    ((not (member org-state org-done-keywords))
     (org-delete-property "TRIGGER"))))

(add-hook 'org-after-todo-state-change-hook 'mm/org-insert-trigger)`}
```

I want to configure the `org-mode` like styled above, but I don't know how.

`mm/org-insert-trigger` What about `mm`? I put the code in .emacs. When I changed the status to 'NEXT', it appears `symbol's value as variable is void.`

Comment: the `mm` is most likely the authors name. To help you solve your problem, please provide backtrace. `(setq debug-on-error t)`

Comment: `unless: Symbol's value as variable is void: org-depend-doing-chain-find-next`

Comment: put `(require 'org-depend)` in your `.emacs` (also called init file).

Comment: @kindahero You should add that as an answer to have it accepted/upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put (require 'org-depend) in your .emacs